# How do I match the root of a content URI in Android 4.3?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'd like to return some results when someone hits the root of my ContentProvider, which has worked fine up until now. As of Android 4.3, however, I cannot match the root! Here's everything I've tried, and nothing will work. This returns -1 under 4.3, but not under earlier versions.

How do I match that URI?

```
private int testMatch(){
    UriMatcher mUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(0);
    mUriMatcher.addURI("com.someone.app.provider.thingy", "/#", 0);
    mUriMatcher.addURI("com.someone.app.provider.thingy", "/", 1);
    mUriMatcher.addURI("com.someone.app.provider.thingy", "", 2);
    mUriMatcher.addURI("com.someone.app.provider.thingy", "/*", 3);
    mUriMatcher.addURI("com.someone.app.provider.thingy", "#", 4);
    mUriMatcher.addURI("com.someone.app.provider.thingy", "*", 5);
    mUriMatcher.addURI("com.someone.app.provider", "thingy", 6);

    Uri uri=Uri.parse("content://com.someone.app.provider.thingy");

    return mUriMatcher.match(uri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, the value passed to the `UriMatcher` constructor is for matching the root path, but in your code the same value (`0`) is overridden by the path `/#`.

Try the following code to see if you can match the root path or not:

```
UriMatcher mUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(0);
Uri uri=Uri.parse("content://com.someone.app.provider.thingy");
return mUriMatcher.match(uri);
```

The reason why it worked before 4.3 is probably due to 4.3 accepting leading `/`.